# SQL Server sort column based on the same column itself

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a db table containing a column `display_order`. The data looks like this:

```
2 
4 
7 
10 
12
```

I want to update the same db column and it should look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Please suggest some easy SQL code.

Comment: does your table have an identity column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look into [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), this will help you here.

e.g. demo that won't update your data, but will show you the current order and the new order based on ROW_NUMBER

```
SELECT display_order AS CurrentDisplayOrder, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY display_order) AS NewDisplayOrder
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY display_order
```

If that produces what you'd expect, then you can just switch it into an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke Depends what you mean by "flagged as inactive" - if that's another column, you should be able to put a `where` clause in before the `Order by`.

Comment: can you provide me the update statement... i tried with this..UPDATE t 
SET t.display_order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY display_order)
FROM [Folder] t
and t.folder_stub='10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'
but it is throwing the error to me as "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.".

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on AdaTheDev's idea - using a CTE (Common Table Expression) makes it really easy to see how to use the actual `UPDATE` to update your table. I'm using a table variable `@work` here to simulate your existing table - just replace my table variable with your own table name:

```
DECLARE @work TABLE (display_order INT)

INSERT INTO @work VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @work VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @work VALUES(7)
INSERT INTO @work VALUES(10)
INSERT INTO @work VALUES(12)

SELECT * FROM @work

;WITH UpdateTable AS
(
    SELECT 
        display_order, new_order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY display_order) 
    FROM @work
)
UPDATE @work
SET display_order = u.new_order
FROM @work w 
INNER JOIN UpdateTable u ON w.display_order = u.display_order

SELECT * FROM @work
```

Comment: Marc, You can do this even more simply and transparently by using the CTE table itself as the target of the update:  ;WITH UpdateTable AS (SELECT display_order, new_order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY display_order) FROM @work) UPDATE UpdateTable SET display_order = new_order . (If there is any possibility the display_order column is not unique, it's important to add a unique column to the ORDER BY clause so that the ROW_NUMBER() value will be deterministic.)

Answer (score 0):

Without CTE (but needs some key in the table)

```
declare @tbl table(id int primary key identity(1,1),Value int)
insert @tbl values(2)
insert @tbl values(5)
insert @tbl values(3)

select * from @tbl 

select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Value) from @tbl order by id

update @tbl set Value = result from @tbl tbl 
inner join (select id, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Value) result from @tbl ) hlp    on tbl.id =hlp.ids

select * from @tbl
```